# Set-based query to find all columns in table that contain at least one null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL and SQL Server 2008 R2. I have found a cursor based approach to find all columns in a particular table that contain null values, but I am hoping to find a simpler set-based solution.

```
USE QC_TEST

DECLARE @colName nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @nullCols nvarchar(max)

SELECT @colName = c.name, @nullCols = COALESCE(@nullCols+', ','')+@colName
FROM sys.tables AS t
    JOIN sys.columns AS c
        ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'myTable' 
AND 
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE c.name IS NULL)

SELECT @colName, @nullCols
```

The above code currently returns all columns in `myTable`. If I change the `EXISTS` clause to `NOT EXISTS`, it returns no columns. The result should be a comma-separated string of column names that contain at least 1 null value.

Thanks for your help

Comment: why? what type of application would need this? also you can add `AND c.is_nullable=1` to your query to only loop over columns that could have a null.

Comment: This is necessary for checking data as it is delivered to us from vendors before we move it to a production database.  This is a standard Quality Control check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because the EXISTS subquery is just checking the name of your column isn't null, which it can't be. The subquery doesn't expand out the "WHERE c.name IS NULL" into "WHERE MyColumnName IS NULL", it just sees that c.name = 'MyColumnName' which is not null and always returns false.

The cursor based approach probably works by building a seperate string query for each column and then excuting the string.

You could unpivot the table and look for nulls in that result set, i.e.

```
WITH myTable_unpvt AS (
    SELECT ContactID, FieldName, FieldValue
    FROM 
       (SELECT ContactID
            , cast(Forename as sql_variant) Forename
            , cast(Surname as sql_variant) Surname
            , cast(Extn as sql_variant) Extn
            , cast(Email as sql_variant) Email
            , cast(Age as sql_variant) Age
       FROM myTable) p
    UNPIVOT
       (FieldValue FOR FieldName IN 
          (Forename, Surname, Extn, Email, Age)
    ) AS myTable_unpvt
)

SELECT DISTINCT FieldName FROM myTable_unpvt WHERE FieldValue IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Is it possible to do this dynamically?  In other words, I need to run this query on multiple tables with different columns.  My hope is to avoid hard-coding column names into the SQL code.

Comment: It would be acceptable to use a cursor to build the queries. You'd only need to re-run it when the table changed, and the size of the task is small enough not to worry about it's speed.

Comment: @Brian: For dynamically, see my answer. The results are in rows (not CSV) but this could be fixed with one additional level of indirection. It's also kind of icky (concatenating strings...).

Answer (score 2):

You could get a result this way

```
declare @sql varchar(max), @t varchar(max);
set @t = 'your_table';
select @sql = (select stuff(
    (select 
            '] is null union select ''' + c.name + 
            ''' from ' + @t + ' where [' + c.name
        from
            (select
                    c.name
                from sys.tables AS t
                inner join sys.columns AS c
                    ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                where
                    t.name = @t
            ) as c
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 16, '' ) + '] is null' )
;
exec(@sql);
```

But I don't know that you'd really consider that better.

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  I am trying it in SSMS right now, but the query results to and error that reads: "The name ... is not a valid identifier." where ... is the long SQL query created and stored in the `@sql` variable, but it is cut-off and incomplete.  WHen I count the number of characters it is much less than the 8,000 that should be allowed in a varchar(max) variable.  Do you have any thoughts on this error?

Comment: @Brian: It is possible that this query could result in a string longer than a `varchar(max)` if you have a lot of columns in the table. Not sure exactly the best way to work around that. You could make it operate in chunks of columns with a little more work, but eww.

Comment: When I `PRINT @sql` before the `EXEC @sql` call, I get the entire string.  Is there a limit to the size of variable the `EXEC` statement can accept?

Comment: @Brian: According to the SQL Server docs: "In earlier versions of SQL Server, character strings are limited to 8,000 bytes. This requires concatenating large strings for dynamic execution. In SQL Server 2005, the varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) data types can be specified that allow for character strings to be up to 2 gigabytes of data." I read this as saying that it should work to `exec(@sql)` where @sql is bigger than 8000 bytes.

Comment: I will also note that a column name with a `'` in it will cause breakage.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I got it working.  My SQL string was not too long, but I was didn't put `@sql` in parenthesis.  In other words...`EXEC @sql` should have been `EXEC(@sql)`

Answer (score 0):

this is a little unconventional, but try this:

```
--set up test table
--the BEGIN TRY and ALTERs allow you to rerun entire script over and over again
BEGIN TRY
    CREATE TABLE YourTable (PK int not null primary key, RowValue1 int null, RowValue2 varchar(5) null, RowValue3 datetime)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH END CATCH
delete YourTable
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN RowValue1 int  NULL
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN RowValue2 varchar(5)  NULL
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN RowValue3 datetime  NULL

--setup test data
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES  (1,1111,'AAAA',GETDATE())
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES  (2,2222,'BBBB',GETDATE())
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES  (3,3333,'CCCC',GETDATE())
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES  (4,NULL,'DDDD',GETDATE())
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES  (5,5555,'EEEE',NULL)

--determine null columns
DECLARE @BadColumns  varchar(50)

BEGIN TRY
    ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN RowValue1 int NOT NULL
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @BadColumns=ISNULL(@BadColumns+', ','')+'RowValue1'
END CATCH    
----------------------------------
BEGIN TRY
    ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN RowValue2 varchar(5) NOT NULL
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @BadColumns=ISNULL(@BadColumns+', ','')+'RowValue2'
END CATCH  
----------------------------------
BEGIN TRY
    ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN RowValue3 datetime NOT NULL
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @BadColumns=ISNULL(@BadColumns+', ','')+'RowValue3'
END CATCH  

--report null columns
SELECT @BadColumns AS [Columns having NULLs]
```

OUTPUT:

```
Columns having NULLs
--------------------------------------------------
RowValue1, RowValue3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

if you need to to be dynamic because you don't know the column names, you can build a similar command into a string and then execute that.